# HOw to Build Ant file for EJB Program in java

Tags: jpa, ant, ejb, build.xml

I have a EJB program written in java,in that i need to create ant build.xml file formy project.

My project has a server, client and JPA class. Ive got the following questions;

1) Do I have to create two build.xml files for both my client and server program or is one build.xml file enough to run my application?

2) How to create the build.xml file for this project.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help. It has sample script for EJB including JPA and client.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16109977/1718893